# Only reading the last line. Python

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a code for school that opens a file, reads through the lines of information, and sorts them into lists, but for some reason it's only reading the last line of code. Any idea why this is happening?

```
open_file = input('Please enter the data file: ')

f = open(open_file, 'r')

listopen1 = []
listopen2 = []
listopen3 = []
listclose1 = []
listclose2 = []
listclose3 = []


for line in f:
    if line == '{': 
        listopen3.append(line)
    elif line == '[':
        listopen2.append(line)
    elif line == '(':
        listopen3.append(line)
    
    elif line == '}':
        listclose1.append(line)
    elif line == ']':
        listclose2.append(line)
    elif line == ')':
        listclose3.append(line)

for items in listopen1:
    print(items)
print('----------')
for items in listopen2:
    print(items)
print('----------')
for items in listopen3:
    print(items)
print('----------')

for items in listclose1:
    print(items)
print('----------')
for items in listclose2:
    print(items)
print('----------')
for items in listclose3:
    print(items)
print('----------')

f.close()
```

This is the txt file its opening to sort:

```
[
[
[
]
]
]
{
(
)    
}
(
)
```

Comment: `for line in f.read().split()`

Comment: File iterators already read files line-by-line on demand; there is no reason to read the entire file into memory before splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your lines are not one character, they also have a newline (e.g. `"[\n"` is the first line), so you need to match `\n`, `strip()` it away, or use something like `.read().splitlines()` which strips it as well.

Comment: As for why the newline is there, a return value of `''` is what signifies you have reached the end of the file, as opposed to an empty line in the file.